# Problems after adding security to Web App SpringBoot & AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have build a Web App with SpringBoot and successfully deployed it on AWS.

But once I added Spring security (Basic Authentication), it works perfect from localhost, but it doesn`t work from AWS ElasticBeanstalk.

Anyone else has this problem?
Possible solutions ?

Comment: Any error are you getting?

Comment: Well, I get that there is no app deployed 404, but there is. If i run the app on localhost it works perfect after deploying it doesn`t.

Comment: So this is the issue you need to search not spring security.